# UDP Socket not reading data from server in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to get data from the UDP server but nothing shows in my client so basically, I send bytes [0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 ] and the server will respond with data so the bytes are being sent successfully I don't know what's going on but the server is 100% fine when I send data using another app I get data back

```
conn2, err := net.Dial("udp", "192.168.1.240:2010")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error dialing remote addr", err)
    }
    request, err := hex.DecodeString("00010203")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    n, err := conn2.Write(request)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unable to send request to weblist")
    }
    log.Printf("\033[33mWeb Server\033[0m : %d bytes sent successfully\n", n)

    var buffer []byte = make([]byte, 1500)
    for {

        // Read from server
        n, err := conn2.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        //log.Printf("\033[33mWeb Server\033[0m : %s replied with %d bytes\n", addr.String(), n)
        encodedStr := hex.EncodeToString(buffer[0:n])

        log.Printf("\033[33mWeb Server\033[0m : %s\n", encodedStr)
    }
```

Same code that runs fine in python

```
def main():
    socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    remote_address = ('192.168.1.240', 2010)
    logging = logging

    socket.sendto(bytes.fromhex('01 02 03 04'), remote_address)
    logging.debug('packet successfully sent')
    while True:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([socket], [], [], 2)
        for s in readable:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
            if data[0:4] == bytes.fromhex('01 02 03 04'):
                packet = bytes.fromhex('01 02 03 04')
                auth_key = bytes(data[4:5] + data[5:6] + data[6:7] + data[7:8])
```

Comment: Please provide a clear description of the problem and ways to reproduce it. *"not reading"* could mean that it hangs, that it panics, that you don't get the expected data .... Also, what other apps work? And do they even work internally like your code is supposed to work? Does the server reply from the same socket or from a different socket? ... . It would be useful if you could provide actual packet captures of the exchange, so one can see that a) the server sends actual data (maybe it doesn't since it expected different/more data from client?) and b) how they look like on the wire.

Comment: I meant by not reading that it waits to get data it hangs and it doesn't panic. what I meant by apps is I have a python script that does the same thing and that communicates with the server and everything works perfectly the client sends hex code 00010203 and then the server answers back with 4 bytes. to be clear I don't have the source 
 code of the server is a public authentication server I just send the code and it replies back with auth key

Comment: If you have a working Python script then please provide it so that one can compare the implementations.

Comment: Are you sending data only from `192.168.1.240:2010`? You normally want an unconnected UDP socket so you can receive from different source ports.

Comment: @jimB 192.168.1.240:2010 is the IP of the server

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added the python code above

Comment: Thanks. I see two main differences: you send different 4 bytes and the Golang code uses a connected UDP socket whereas the Python code does not. The last things means that your Golang code expects the server to send the response from "192.168.1.240:2010" whereas your Python code will accept data from anywhere, different IP address and also different ports. It might be useful to have a closer look at the `addr` you get from `recvfrom` in Python and check if it exactly (ip and port) matches the `remote_address` you've send to.

Comment: can u please help me with some code I still don't see the difference

Comment: use `Listen` or `ListenUDP` to create a listening socket which will accept packets from any location.